# In the CSS declaration 'align-content', is there any difference between the values 'normal' and 'stretch'?

Tags: css, flexbox

The default value of the CSS declaration 'align-content' is 'normal'. However, there is another declaration: 'stretch', and I'm struggling to identify a single difference between the two of them. Are they identical (with perhaps one of them being obsolete)?

I played around with the Inspector tool on Chrome on a test website I created using HTML and CSS, and did the between those two values made zero difference in the appearance of the site.

Comment: Post your HTML and the CSS you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the definitions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content):

`align-content: normal`: *The items are packed in their default position as if no align-content value was set*

`align-content: stretch`: *If the combined size of the items along the cross axis is less than the size of the alignment container, any auto-sized items have their size increased equally (not proportionally), while still respecting the constraints imposed by max-height/max-width (or equivalent functionality), so that the combined size exactly fills the alignment container along the cross axis.*

but i think in the browser the normal and stretch values pretty much work the same way for most cases. the different is that with `stretch` 'auto'-sized items to fi the container

There is also some good information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350959/what-are-the-default-values-for-justify-content-align-content) and [here on CSS_Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-content/)

Comment: Thank you! Slightly confusing, but it makes sense. I appreciate your comment.